# which statistical test to use to check if there is any correlation between values of the same categorical variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, data-visualization

I have data which looks like this

```
          Reason 1    Reason 2     Reason 3
  ----------------------------------------------
 Year 1 |     20    |    120    |    120    |
 Year 2 |     220   |    20     |    2120   |
 Year 3 |   2053    |    1120   |    1200   |
 Year 4 |     30    |    3120   |     12    |
```

I now want to know if there is any kind of correlation between Reason 1  and 
the other two reasons. The idea is if I tackle reason 1, is there any way of telling it might also affect reason 2 and reason 3 ? Which test should I use to check this?  The numbers indicate the frequency of occurrence.

Comment: A chisquare test? Search this site, for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102680/multiple-testing-contingency-table-or-logistic-regression-approach-for-survey or  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/961/statistical-test-for-n-x-m-contingency-tables  or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147721/which-is-the-best-visualization-for-contingency-tables or ...